# Program creating a list within a list when reading contents of file

Tags: python, list

I have found a fix for the following problem, however I'd like to understand why my below code creates a list of strings within a list, i.e. has this list of strings as the only element in an outer list.

I have a .txt file which I'm reading in which consists of about 25 sentences. It is just one long paragraph and so I wanted to split it into sentences, delimited by a full stop.
I initially used this code to perform this step:

```
file = open("love_life.txt", "r")

list_of_sentences = []
for line in file:
    new = line.split('.')
    list_of_sentences.append(new)
file.close()
print(list_of_sentences)
```

I expected that this would create a list of strings, with each string representing a sentence delimited by a full stop. But instead, although it indeed created a list of strings/sentences it did so enclosed within another list. So when I tried to iterate over the list, I was just iterating one time over the nested list. Like this output:

```
[["lifeguards save lives", "time is of the essence", "the wind blows where it wants"]]
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `line.split('.')` returns a list, and `list_of_sentences.append(new)` adds that list to `list_of_sentences`. Maybe you meant to use `list_of_sentences.extend(new)` instead? That would add *each element* of `new` to `list_of_sentences`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just wondering, why does line.split('.') return a list?

Comment: @timman I don't know why you think it would return a string. It takes a string and splits it into multiple strings, which get returned in a list. Check out the documentation: [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Got it! Line is a string, but new is a list. Amazing, thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **extend()**, if you dont want to end up with a list of list.

```
    file = open("love_life.txt", "r")

    list_of_sentences = []
    for line in file:
        new = line.split('.')
        list_of_sentences.append(new)
    file.close()
    print(list_of_sentences)
```